# Is there a way to take multiple inputs separated on different lines WITHOUT LOOPS?

Tags: python-3.x

Input:
fname
lname
address

Output:
[fname, lname, address]

Answer (score 0):

You can use method `.split()` on String objects as follow

```
input = """
   fname
   lname
   address
   """

output = input.split("\n")

assert output == ['fname', 'lname', 'address']
```

Comment: This is standard input not just a string!